# Why is the Uniform Boundedness Theorem not true for all normed vector spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis

A tentative statement of the Uniform Boundedness Theorem for any normed vector space would be

> Let $(T_n)$ be a sequence of bounded linear operators $T_n:X\to Y$ such that $(\|T_n x\|)$ is bounded for every $x\in X$. Then the sequence of the norms $\|T_n\|$ is bounded, that is, there is a $c$ such that $\|T_n\|\leq c$.

Let us assume that $\|T_n\|\not \leq c$ for some $c\in \Bbb{R}$. This would directly imply that for some $x\in X$, the sequence $(\|T_nx\|)$ would also not be bounded. QED.

How is the argument wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may be misunderstanding the theorem: it would propose that there exists $c$ such that *for all* $n$ we have $\|T_n\| \le c$.  The negation would be that *for all* $c$ *there exists* $n$ with $\|T_n\| > c$.  Also, think carefully about "this would directly imply"!  Look at the definitions!

Comment: @NateEldredge- Going by your comment, I feel I have not misunderstood the concepts involved. If $\|T_n\|\not\leq c$ _for all $n$_, then for any real number $c\in\Bbb{R}$, there exists a $T_n$ such that $\|T_n\|>c$. You're right. Now we know that as every $T_j$ is a linear bounded operator, $\|T_n x\|\leq \|T_n\|\|x\|$. Hence, as for any real number $c$ we have some $\|T_n\|>c$, for any real number $c$, we also have some $\|T_n x\|$ greater than $c$ for at least one $x\in X$.

Comment: The $x$ such that $||T_nx|| > c$ depends on $n$, so there is no contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, consider the normed vector space $V$ of sequences $s = (s_1,s_2,\ldots)$ that have only finitely many nonzero elements, with $\|s\| = \max_n |s_n|$.
Define $T_n : V \to \mathbb R$ by $T_n s = n s_n$.  For every $s \in V$,  all but finitely many $T_n s$ are $0$, so $\{\|T_n s\|: n \in {\mathbb N}\}$ is a finite set and thus bounded.  But $\|T_n\| = n$, so $\{\|T_n\|: n \in {\mathbb N}\} = \mathbb N$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that
$$
\|T_n\| = \sup_{\|x\| = 1} \|T_n(x)\|
$$
So if $\|T_n\|$ is unbounded, then the set
$$
S := \{\|T_n(x)\| : n \in \mathbb{N}, \|x\| = 1\}
$$
is unbounded. This does not mean that each subset
$$
S_x = \{\|T_n(x)\| : n \in \mathbb{N}\}
$$
is unbounded.

There are infinitely many such $S_x$, so it is possible that each $S_x$ is bounded, even though $S$ is not.

Comment: I said that there has to exist at least one $x\in X$ such that $\{\|T_n(x)\|\}$ is unbounded. I did not say that $\{\|T_n(x)\|\}$ is unbounded for every $x\in X$.

Comment: Exactly my point. There may not exist any $x \in X$ such that $S_x$ is unbounded. They may all be bounded.